# I am trying to create this table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS
(Department_Id varchar(5) Primary Key NOT NULL,
 Department_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
 Manager_Id varchar(5) FOREIGN KEY REFRENCES EMPLOYEES,
 Location_Id FOREIGN KEY REFRENCES LOCATIONS)
GO

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES
(Employee_Id varchar Primary Key NOT NULL,
 First_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
 Last_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
 Email varchar(60) NULL,
 PhoneNumber varchar(13) NULL,
 Hire_Date date NOT NULL,
 Manager_ID varchar(5) FOREIGN KEY REFRENCES EMPLOYEES
 Department_IdFK REFRENCES DEPARTMENTS)
GO

CREATE TABLE LOCATIONS
(Location_ID varchar(5) Primary Key,
 Postal_Code no(5),
 City text(60),
 State_Province text(20),
 Country text(60))
```

Comment: Those aren't SQL Server or MySQL data types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd leave the constraints off, but here you go.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS (
Department_Id varchar(5) Primary Key,
Department_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Manager_Id varchar(5),
Location_Id varchar(5)
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
Employee_Id varchar(5) Primary Key,
First_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Email varchar(60) NULL,
PhoneNumber varchar(13) NULL, 
Hire_Date date NOT NULL,
Manager_ID varchar(5),
Department_Id varchar(5)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE LOCATIONS (
Location_ID varchar(5) Primary Key,
Postal_Code varchar(5),
City varchar(60),
State_Province varchar(20),
Country varchar(60)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENTS WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DepartmentManager] FOREIGN KEY([Manager_Id])
REFERENCES EMPLOYEES ([Employee_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENTS WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserLocation] FOREIGN KEY([Location_Id])
REFERENCES LOCATIONS ([Location_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeManager] FOREIGN KEY([Manager_Id])
REFERENCES EMPLOYEES ([Employee_Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEES WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeDepartment] FOREIGN KEY([Department_Id])
REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS ([Department_Id])
GO
```

Comment: +1: You beat me to it.  Besides the typos and the questionable data types, the main problem would be the foreign key references between the `DEPARTMENTS` and the `EMPLOYEES` tables.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `REFERENCES` as `REFRENCES` multiple times.  Try spelling it correctly to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed there were more problems, but I figured start with the typos.  I only looked at it briefly.

Answer (score 1):

```
DEPARTMENTS REFERENCES EMPLOYEES
EMPLOYEES REFERENCES EMPLOYEES
```

This makes these tables difficult to work with. It seems you are allowing these to be `NULL`able in the knowledge that to be able to create two entities in two tables you need two `INSERT`s plus two `UPDATE`s.

Also, it seems to allow an employee's manager to be different from her department's manager -- is this intended?

I would 'design out' the need for `NULL`able referenced/referencing columns and create two further relationship tables:

```
DepartmentalStaff REFERENCES Employees REFERENCES Departments
DepartmentalManagers REFERENCES DepartmentalStaff
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what database this is intended for, and you have some really odd data types in there....

Some general comments though (which apply mostly to SQL Server):

- in general, short strings (under 10 chars) can and should be made `CHAR(x)` - so your `Department_Id` really should be a `char(5)` field
- `CHAR(X)` fields are (at least in SQL Server) always padded to their full length with spaces - so if you have `Department_Id CHAR(5)` and you enter `'ABC'`, the column will contain `'ABC..'`
- therefore, columns like first name and last name should definitely **not** be `CHAR(20)` - if you put 'Bruce' into `first_name`, you'll end up with 'Bruce...............' - good luck trying to find anything on such a column! Use `VARCHAR(20)` instead!
- if you're really using SQL Server 2005 and up, you should stop using `TEXT` - that datatype has been deprecated. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead - it has all the benefits of TEXT, plus you can use all the usual string functions on it.
- my personal recommendation would also be to use `INT` for things like `Location_Id` - typically, joining and searching on an INT is faster than a VARCHAR(5) - plus with the INT, you never have to worry about misspelling it, having the wrong collation, or uppercase/lowercase issues. If you use a non-descriptive surrogate column for your ID's, which I think is a good thing, I'd make it an INT - don't use strings for IDs - it tends to get messy (except in places where the strings are used all over the place - like the state abbreviations and so forth)

Comment: "last name should definitely not be CHAR(20)... good luck trying to find anything on such a column!" -- I don't think this is quite the problem you think it is. 'ANSI padding' ensures that when comparing strings of differing lengths the shorter are padded with space characters anyhow. Give it a try :)